# Android Listview countdown timer is causing strange results

Tags: java, android, listview, countdowntimer

I have a listview and want to countdown each item.  My issue is when I scroll the countdown times jump around to incorrect items (so it shows another items countdown time) and there is no rhyme or reason to it?  here is the code

```
private final Map<String, TextView> mcounterlist= new HashMap<String, TextView>();
```

Then in my getview on my adapater I do

```
String gmtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(gmtFormat);
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
Date dd = null;
try {
    dd = sdf.parse(o.endAt);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Date now = new Date();
String sss = timeCalculate((dd.getTime() /1000)- (now.getTime() /1000) ); 
ea.setText("Time Left: " + sss);
TextView cdi =  new TextView();
mcounterlist.put(o.id , cdi);
```

So at this point I I just run a repeating thread to update.

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

       // TextView textView;
        String gmtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault() ;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(gmtFormat);
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
        // if counters are active


        if(mcounterlist.size() > 0)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_orders.size() && i < mcounterlist.size() ;i++) {
            Order o = m_orders.get(i);   
            TextView c = mcounterlist.get(o.id);

                Date dd = null;
                try {
                    dd = sdf.parse(o.endAt);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Date now = new Date();

         long l = (dd.getTime() /1000)- (now.getTime() /1000);
         String sss;
         if (l < 0)
         {
         sss = "ENDED";
         }
         else
         {
             sss = timeCalculate(l);
         }

                if(l < 60 * 60 * 24)
                {
                    c.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E3170D"));
                }
                else
                {
                c.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
                }

             c.setText("Time Left: " + sss);

            }          
        } 




            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

    }
};
```

But when I scroll through my list, the textviews jump all over the place.  I believe part of my issue is related to how I sort the list every 30 seconds, but the ID's of the items don't change.   Is there anything obvious that is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that the views in a listview get reused, the solution was to implement the following change the id to the position in my hashmap and put it in GETVIEW

```
  mcounterlist.remove(position);
  mcounterlist.put(position , ea);
```

You probably don't need to remove the position, but I left it in there since I spent a hour on this, and it works so I don't wnat to change anything:)

Then in my repeat task I need to exclude anyitem not visibe, so here is my handler code

```
int fp  = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() -1 < 0 ? 0 :lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() -1;
            int lp = lv.getLastVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = fp; i < mcounterlist.size() && i < lp;i++) {
            //Log.i("TEST231231",String.valueOf(i));

            if (i  <  lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() -1 )
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (i >= lv.getLastVisiblePosition())
            {
            continue;
            }
            //my adapter list
             Order o = m_orders.get(i);   
            //since I set the position as the refereance, I can use that for the hashmap
            TextView c = mcounterlist.get(i);
```

...

So in essance since the same textviews were getting recycled, I could not update all of them because items that were not on the list were sharing the active text boxes.  To eliminate this issue, I check and only edit the textboxes for items that are visible.